# Is it a problem in Wine: small and upper caps?

Tags: wine, filesystem, playonlinux

Is it a problem if a folder exists in Wine / PlayOnLinux twice? For example 'Music' and 'music' or 'Obse' and 'obse'. Shouldn't it be changed, because windows doesn't differentiate between small and upper caps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it wont segfault, but it might not do what you want. There is or was an option to disable case folding in wine, but last time I checked it didn't work right. It might have been fixed, but ...  Anyway if you aren't using that option when you have two files (or directories) that have names that only differ by case, wine will just pick one and from my experience four out of five times the one I didn't want. If you have requirements to have both case names for other applications, using links (soft or hard) to make the two names point to the same file makes the problem go away.